# STM32 I2C Slave Receiving Executed Only Once with DMA in HAL Library

Tags: stm32, i2c, dma

Currently, I am implementing I2C transfer with DMA to get a fixed number of bytes.

STM32 MCU: `STM32L152RDT6`

STM32 is `slave` and Arduino is `master`.

I have implemented in Arduino which will send I2C command for 3 bytes each time.

However, the callback function `HAL_I2C_SlaveRxCpltCallback` executed only once.

[image: DMA Configuration]
I set DMA request mode to `circular` for both RX and TX to continuously receive same number of bytes.

[image: NVIC Configuration]

In `main.c` For initialization of I2C:

```c
static void MX_I2C1_Init(void)
{

  hi2c1.Instance = I2C1;
  hi2c1.Init.ClockSpeed = 400000;
  hi2c1.Init.DutyCycle = I2C_DUTYCYCLE_2;
  hi2c1.Init.OwnAddress1 = I2C_ADDRESS*2; //I2C_ADDRESS = 0x30
  hi2c1.Init.AddressingMode = I2C_ADDRESSINGMODE_7BIT;
  hi2c1.Init.DualAddressMode = I2C_DUALADDRESS_DISABLE;
  hi2c1.Init.OwnAddress2 = 0;
  hi2c1.Init.GeneralCallMode = I2C_GENERALCALL_DISABLE;
  hi2c1.Init.NoStretchMode = I2C_NOSTRETCH_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_I2C_Init(&hi2c1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  HAL_I2C_Slave_Receive_DMA( &hi2c1,  ucRxbuffer_obc, 3); //Try to get 3 bytes from master

}
```

About `HAL_I2C_MspInit` function in `stm32lxx_hal_msp.c`:
I have checked other examples, which said order of `__HAL_RCC_I2C1_CLK_ENABLE()` need to moved before `GPIO_Init`.

```c
void HAL_I2C_MspInit(I2C_HandleTypeDef* hi2c)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};
  if(hi2c->Instance==I2C1)
  {

    __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();

    /* Peripheral clock enable */
    __HAL_RCC_I2C1_CLK_ENABLE();


    /* I2C1 DMA Init */
    /* I2C1_RX Init */
    hdma_i2c1_rx.Instance = DMA1_Channel7;
    hdma_i2c1_rx.Init.Direction = DMA_PERIPH_TO_MEMORY;
    hdma_i2c1_rx.Init.PeriphInc = DMA_PINC_DISABLE;
    hdma_i2c1_rx.Init.MemInc = DMA_MINC_ENABLE;
    hdma_i2c1_rx.Init.PeriphDataAlignment = DMA_PDATAALIGN_BYTE;
    hdma_i2c1_rx.Init.MemDataAlignment = DMA_MDATAALIGN_BYTE;
    hdma_i2c1_rx.Init.Mode = DMA_CIRCULAR;
    hdma_i2c1_rx.Init.Priority = DMA_PRIORITY_LOW;
    if (HAL_DMA_Init(&hdma_i2c1_rx) != HAL_OK)
    {
      Error_Handler();
    }

    __HAL_LINKDMA(hi2c,hdmarx,hdma_i2c1_rx);


    /* I2C1_TX Init */
    hdma_i2c1_tx.Instance = DMA1_Channel6;
    hdma_i2c1_tx.Init.Direction = DMA_MEMORY_TO_PERIPH;
    hdma_i2c1_tx.Init.PeriphInc = DMA_PINC_DISABLE;
    hdma_i2c1_tx.Init.MemInc = DMA_MINC_ENABLE;
    hdma_i2c1_tx.Init.PeriphDataAlignment = DMA_PDATAALIGN_BYTE;
    hdma_i2c1_tx.Init.MemDataAlignment = DMA_MDATAALIGN_BYTE;
    hdma_i2c1_tx.Init.Mode = DMA_CIRCULAR;
    hdma_i2c1_tx.Init.Priority = DMA_PRIORITY_LOW;
    if (HAL_DMA_Init(&hdma_i2c1_tx) != HAL_OK)
    {
      Error_Handler();
    }

    __HAL_LINKDMA(hi2c,hdmatx,hdma_i2c1_tx);

    /* I2C1 interrupt Init */
    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(I2C1_EV_IRQn, 5, 0);
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(I2C1_EV_IRQn);
    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(I2C1_ER_IRQn, 5, 0);
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(I2C1_ER_IRQn);

    /**I2C1 GPIO Configuration    
    PB6     ------> I2C1_SCL
    PB7     ------> I2C1_SDA 
    */
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_6|GPIO_PIN_7;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_OD;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLUP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF4_I2C1;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

}
```

Finally, the callback function:

```c
void HAL_I2C_SlaveRxCpltCallback(I2C_HandleTypeDef *hi2c)
{
     sprintf(cMessage, "message[0]: %u\n\r", ucRxbuffer_obc[0]);
     debugprintf(cMessage); // It is function like printf and have been tested.
}
```

However, the call back function only be triggered in first time.

Is there anything I miss to set?

Answer (score 0):

what I know is the Callback "disables" the interrupt so you have to re-enable it inside